# Does the C++ standard library at any point include native headers per platform?

Tags: c++, winapi, stl

I'm in an argument with someone who is determined that the C++ standard library such as `algorithm`, `memory`, `string` etc. uses the Windows API header for performing some operations.

Is this the case or not?
I understand that all Windows PEs include native DLLs from the WinAPI but I'm not sure that the standard library is at all compiler/os dependent.

Comment: The standard library is allowed to be compiler/OS-dependent. For example, they will often take advantage of compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: @RaymondChen I just can't think of a reason why the standard library would ever need to use the Windows API though. Under the hood, surely the implementation for Windows could just use C for areas where it uses the WinAPI. I can't think of any use-case for the WinAPI or even *nix libs in the standard library.

Comment: @struction: C++ exceptions on Windows are modeled on top of SEH exceptions. Those are implemented using a mixture of compiler extensions and the CRT. This is just **one** of thousands of reasons, why the C++ Standard Library (or the CRT) needs to use OS specific implementations. It seems you haven't quite understood, that the CRT is implemented on top of the Windows API. Not the other way around.

Comment: <windows.h> is such a pig that no standard library implementor would pull it into user-visible headers.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The question is asking about **using** the Windows API to implement certain features of the C++ Standard Library. Yes, that is generally the case. And yes, this often implies including *Windows.h* for the implementation. Not sure what statement you were trying to make, but it didn't turn out to be very useful.

Comment: @IInspectable - the question asks about "`algorithm`, `memory`, `string`, etc."; those are **headers** that define **templates**. No standard library implementor (which includes me) would use <windows.h> in any of those headers; this can sometimes result in awkward-looking code. Not sure what point you were trying to make, but thank you for your input.

Comment: @struction How would you implement `std::thread` in plain standard C? There is no C standard for threads.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Absolute statements can easily be disputed. Behind the *"etc."* part are headers like `stdexcept`. Now call me crazy, but there is not much template code in there, now is it? You probably interpreted the question to mean *"Does the C++ Standard Library headers **directly** include Windows.h?"*. But that's not what it says.

Comment: @PeteBecker, How would you implement `vector` without OS dependent headers? You said `new`, well, that might be using `HeapAlloc`.

Comment: @Ajay - yes, that's the core problem. But the code for allocating memory (`operator new` and, underneath, `malloc`) lives in source files that get compiled into the library that you link to. It's not in any of the headers that users use.

Comment: @PeteBecker, So, are you saying that new/malloc code would allocate memory without any OS API, OS service or any kernel call coming into picture? Then, you are totally wrong. IF not, clarify your statement.

Comment: @Ajay - please note that I've been involved in implementing the standard library for most of my career. If something I've said seems "totally wrong" then there's a good chance that you've misunderstood. What I **said** is that the **implementation** of the memory management functions is in a separate file, and **calling** those functions does not require knowledge of how they are implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard library is a set of `#include <>` directives that, when inserted into a C++ program, have effects defined by the standard.

Technically they need not be files at all -- all `#include <blah>` directives mandated by the standard could instead be compiler intrinsics that modify the behavior of programs after the directive.

In practice, they are usually a mixture of pure C++ header file code, header file code that uses compiler intrinsics or platform-specific details, and libraries, where the libraries are implemented in a mixture of OS-specific, hardware-specific, or in C/C++.

There are parts of the C++ standard library that cannot be implemented in C++.

Comment: But does any header files in the standard library ever explicitly #include <Windows.h> ? I can only imagine it would for memory stuff (but then again why bother, the standard could just use C without using WinAPI) since the standard library exposes no system-specific APIs

Comment: @struction: The CRT is not some magic bullet, that can sidestep the OS it is compiled for. At some point, the CRT must use OS specific functionality (memory management, file access, exception handling, and so on). Whether or not any C++ library 'file' from your particular implementation includes *Windows.h* is not at all interesting. The CRT and(/or) the C++ Standard Library is compiler/OS-specific at some point.

Comment: @IInspectable: `windows.h` defines a whole bunch of stuff that could conflict with the user's code, so it's hardly uninteresting.  I'd actually expect the standard to prohibit this, for the obvious reasons.  (Obviously the source code for the library itself must use `windows.h` but that's not the same as one of the standard include files using it.)

Comment: The standard is permitted to include *other* `std` header files (any or none).  It is permitted to introduce symbols in the global namespace starting with `_A` or any other capital letter, or a `__` anywhere in the symbol.  It can do almost anything within `std` above and beyond what the standard says, so long as standard compliant code compiles.  It may not make a standard-compliant program fail; the standard is defined in terms of behavior, not "what code it includes".  If `#include "windows.h"` would make an otherwise standard compliant program fail to compile, it may not include it.

Comment: For the record, including `windows.h` will indisputably make otherwise standard compliant programs fail to compile. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The question is asking, whether the C++ Standard Library **uses** the Windows API. To answer that question, it is not at all interesting, whether the C++ Standard Library **implementation** includes *Windows.h*, some other Windows API header file, or other header files that do (like those of the CRT). A compliant implementation will not pull the Windows API declarations into the global namespace in a user-visible way. And that's really the only interesting take-away from this question (for some definition of *interesting*).

Comment: @IInspectable: the intent of the question is unclear IMO.  But the comment to which you were replying asked specifically about standard header files directly including windows.h.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Again, not quite on spot. The comment asked for header files in the standard library, not standard header files. And some internal header files may include *Windows.h*, in a way that's compliant with the language specification. But, as I said before, it is a completely irrelevant, uninteresting implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, the standard library can (and does) makes use of platform specific headers.

Long answer:
The interface exposed to the user is the same across platforms, but the implementation may make use of platform + compiler specific features.

Want proof?
Find the include directory for your compiler, for example, the latest visual studio is here (by default):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include

Go to this directory on the command line and run:

`findstr -s -n -i -l "<windows.h>" *`

On my machine, this outputs:

```
delayhlp.cpp:25:#include <windows.h>
msclr\marshal.h:20:#include <windows.h>
msclr\marshal_windows.h:18:#include <windows.h>
vccorlib.h:34:#include <windows.h>
vsgcapture.h:4:#include <Windows.h>
```

So yes, windows.h is included by multiple implementation files.

---

**Edit in response to comments:**

Examining the file "thread" in the visual studio include directory reveals the implementation of std::thread::join is:

```
inline void thread::join()
    {   // join thread
    if (!joinable())
        _Throw_Cpp_error(_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    if (_Thr_is_null(_Thr))
        _Throw_Cpp_error(_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    if (get_id() == _STD this_thread::get_id())
        _Throw_Cpp_error(_RESOURCE_DEADLOCK_WOULD_OCCUR);
    if (_Thrd_join(_Thr, 0) != _Thrd_success)
        _Throw_Cpp_error(_NO_SUCH_PROCESS);
    _Thr_set_null(_Thr);
}
```

The various `_Thrd_XXX` functions are defined in `cthread.c`, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\stl`

For example, _Thrd_join is:

```
int _Thrd_join(_Thrd_t thr, int *code)
    {   /* return exit code when thread terminates */
    unsigned long res;
    if (WaitForSingleObjectEx(thr._Hnd, INFINITE, FALSE) == WAIT_FAILED
        || GetExitCodeThread(thr._Hnd, &res) == 0)
        return (_Thrd_error);
    if (code)
        *code = (int)res;
    return (CloseHandle(thr._Hnd) == 0 ? _Thrd_error : _Thrd_success);
}
```

Which uses various windows api functions, like `WaitForSingleObjectEx`

So it seems that although "windows.h" isn't visible to users of standard libary headers, it is used in the implementation of these functions.

Note that the implementation files (such as cthread.c) include "windows.h" via a file "wrapwin.h" in the same directory, which, according to comments in the file, is to suppress compiler warnings in "windows.h"

Comment: Is that not just Windows compiler related stuff like the Visual Studio compiler? Those files look like part of the CLR rather than the C++ STL

Comment: None of those implementation files are included via any standard headers, as far as I can tell, though :)

Comment: And the ucrt also seems clean of Windows.h or Winuser.h includes.

Comment: Edited answer in response to this, I think this shows that std::thread is using the windows api

Comment: Well, *of course* std::thread is using the Windows API.  That doesn't mean  that it's part of the standard include files.

Comment: @struction, Did you say "CLR" - Well, no!

Comment: @HarryJohnston the question is about whether "the C++ standard library such as algorithm, memory, string etc. uses the Windows API header for performing some operations". 
My interpretation is that the question is asking if windows.h is used at all by the standard library, be that part of the implementation or part of the standard include files.

Comment: My interpretation is that what the OP *really* wanted to know was whether including a standard header file resulted in also including windows.h; after all, that's the only part that matters when you're writing code using the standard library.  But I'm also not sure they quite understood the distinction between the two interpretations, which may be why the question is so unclear.